# What is the C# equivalent for java Collections emptySet()

Tags: c#, collections

In my code I would like to return an empty set.

In java I can use static `emptySet()` method of standard `Collections` class.

Does the equivalent method/constant exist for the C# ?

=====
Part of the code:

```
    private static HashSet<string> CreateSetWithProcessedIds()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(processedIdsFilePath))
        {
            // return empty set here
        }


    }
```

Edit 2:

I would like to return an empty and immutable set, when there's no saved data present. If saved data present, I want to create a HashSet and return it to the caller process. Caller process will use this set in readonly mode.

Comment: Maybe [Enumerable.Empty<TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.empty)?

Comment: What are you looking for in the first place? Don't expect people to know what `emptySet()` does or how you want to use it. You can create singleton empty enumerables with `Enumerable.Empty`, empty singleton arrays with `Array.Empty`

Comment: `Array.Empty` / `Enumerable.Empty` / `new CollectionNameHere()` The latter isn't immutable though.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do and why do you want a *set*? If it's going to be empty, isn't an `IEnumerable<T>` enough? If not, why not create a singleton empty set and store it as an `IReadOnlySet`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my method produces a hashset, but in some conditions it should return an empty set.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablehashset-1.empty?view=net-5.0 - immutable empty set.

Comment: @Rafael post the code in the question itself. Does the set have to be editable? If not, you don't need to return a `HashSet`. BTW what *do* you return? You could return an `IReadOnlySet` instead, and return a cached empty set as needed

Comment: Read-only != Immutable. Read-only means you can't add anything. Immutable means that changes don't modify the original data and only the modifier sees the changes. Both are very useful for eg writing thread-safe code

Comment: @Rafael you still don't explain what you want to do. If you want to return a mutable HashSet you don't need `emptySet()` or its equivalent. Just `return new HashSet<string>()`. If you don't want the set to be mutable use `IReadOnlySet<string>` instead. You can return `ImmutableHashSet<string>.Empty` if the file isn't found

Comment: @Rafael maybe you want an `IReadOnlySet<string>`? Maybe an `ImmutableHashSet<string>` ? It depends on what you want to do if no file is found. Are you just reading some data from the set? In that case `IReadOnlySet` is enough. Are you adding extra values if the file exists? Why not use a `HashSet` then?  Are you trying to use an empty set as a non-null default that would just delay throwing an exception if someone tried to incorrectly add an item? Because that's what `Set.Add` would do. It would be safer to return `HashSet<string>?` in C# 8 and later, or `(bool,HashSet<string>?)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would like to return an immutable empty set. My method returns `HashSet<string>`, so I want to return empty set, to run the parent process smoothly when there's no saved data present. In general returned set (with data) also will be used in readonly mode.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've updated my questions again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the set is read-only, the return type should change to `IReadOnlySet<T>`.
The [IReadOnlySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlyset-1?view=net-5.0) interface provides set functionality without any modification methods. Returning `IReadOnlySet` means that the code won't even compile if someone tries to modify it.

```
private static IReadOnlySet<string> CreateSetWithProcessedIds()
{
    if (!File.Exists(processedIdsFilePath))
    {
        return Immutable.ImmutableHashSet<string>.Empty;
    }

    var mySet=new HashSet<string>();
    ...
    return mySet;

}
```

The [ImmutableHashSet.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablehashset-1.empty?view=net-5.0) field contains a static immutable hashset instance which implements `IReadOnlySet<T>`, so it can be used whenever an `IReadOnlySet<T>` is needed.

The [Immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-5.0) are similar to "normal" arrays, dictionaries and sets, but any modification operations return a *new* collection with the modified data instead of modifying the original. This means they're thread-safe for both reading and writing, and any changes are only visible to the modifying code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if you find this cleaner than standard instantiation

```
HashSet<int> hs = Enumerable.Empty<int>().ToHashSet();
```

Comment: That's no different than `new HashSet<int>()`. `ToHashSet()` will create a new mutable `HashSet`

Comment: I agree, this is just an extra step to achieve nothing more than a new HashSet